# Number of Atoms in a State with a Constant Time T with Decay

Tags: electrons, ground-state

A state of energy E1 with a lifetime of T1 decays into the state of energy E2. The state of E2 then decays with a lifetime of T2 into the state of E3. It is known T1 = 2T2. Initially all of the atoms with quantity No are in the E1 State. Calculate the number of atoms N2 which are in the state E2 at any constant time T.

The answer is N_o(e^(-t/T1) - e^(-2t/T1) )

I absolutely have no idea what formulas they used on this; Requesting any hint on where to start? Topics I have to study? formulas I have to keep in mind?

Comment: Can you write down the differential equations for the process?

Answer (score 0):

The decay is proportional to the number of atoms left. Where growth (or decay) is proportional to the size of the population, you have exponential growth (or decay). In fact the time constant is basically defined in terms of this exponential.